# Check how many sites are running on Azure cloud

Tags: azure

When i looked into my **Cloud Service** i saw there is option called **Sites**

The clould service contains serveral sites like --

```
Demosite1.com
demosites2.com
and so on...
```

But i really do not know where to find --

**how many sites are running in a cloud service or even in a subscription on Azure**`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is this on the classic portal with the classical cloud service? Have you tried the ASM powershell commands?

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno no i did not tried ASM powershell commands ....

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno do you know how to get the current running sites using ASM powershell commands

Comment: Is this a classic portal or on the new one do you have a printscreen ?

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno i added the printscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple command will do in powershell 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj152880.aspx

`Get-AzureService`

You can use the rest api and do that on .Net also or any other language the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460781.aspx

there is also one example there how to do it in c#

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer